# How to calculate sum of fields using mongoose and nodejs api based on a search result

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve the sum of some fields based on a search result and filter and I want to do the summation and apply it only to the search result

[image]

[image]

In my application based on nodejs and mongoose, I have a search process for the user's payment transaction records, which are divided into two parts, or filtered into two parts, which are the balance consumption records and the balance top-up records as follows

I do a filtering process through Query while searching and retrieving records. This is the result of the search

[image]

What I really want is to create a new dummy field that does not exist in the database, and it is included in the data returned from the request sent in the previous image, and it calculates the total points based on the search result

I found this code online and tried it

I tried to configure it to fit the data I had

This code returns the result separately from the search process that I intend to retrieve, and this is normal since it contains a different result

It also returns the result of collecting points for all users, and this is something I do not need

```
 History.aggregate(
      [{ $group: { _id: "$userId", total: {  $sum: "$point"}}}],
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(result);}});
```

**this  findAllHistory**

```
const findAllHistory = async (req,res) => {
  try {
    let loginUser = { _id: req.user.id };
    let foundUserLogin = await dbService.findOne(user, loginUser);
    let options = {};
    let query = {};
    let validateRequest = validation.validateFilterWithJoi(
      req.body,
      HistorySchemaKey.findFilterKeys,
      History.schema.obj
    );
    if (!validateRequest.isValid) {
      return res.validationError({ message: `${validateRequest.message}` });
    }
    if (typeof req.body.query === 'object' && req.body.query !== null) {
      query = { ...req.body.query };
    }

    query.categoryHistory = {$ne: 1};
    query.payeeId = req.user.id;

    if (req.body.isCountOnly){
      let totalRecords = await dbService.count(History, query);
      return res.success({ data: { totalRecords } });
    }
    if (req.body && typeof req.body.options === 'object' && req.body.options !== null) {
      options = { ...req.body.options };
    }
  // let foundHistorys = await dbService.paginate(History,{ $or: [ { payeeId: req.user.id }, { categoryHistory: { $lt: 4 } } ] } );
    let foundHistorys = await dbService.paginate( History,query,options);
    if (!foundHistorys || !foundHistorys.data || !foundHistorys.data.length){
      return res.recordNotFound(); 
    }
/*    History.aggregate(
      [{ $group: { _id: "$userId", total: {  $sum: "$point"}}}],
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(result);}});
*/
    return res.success({ data :foundHistorys });
  } catch (error){
    return res.internalServerError({ message:error.message });
  }
};
```

**this Schema**

```
const myCustomLabels = {
  totalDocs: "itemCount",
  docs: "data",
  limit: "perPage",
  page: "currentPage",
  nextPage: "next",
  prevPage: "prev",
  totalPages: "pageCount",
  pagingCounter: "slNo",
  meta: "paginator",
};
mongoosePaginate.paginate.options = { customLabels: myCustomLabels };
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const schema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },

  isDeleted: { type: Boolean },

  date: { type: Date },

  point: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    unique: false,
    required: true,
  },

  description: {
    lowercase: false,
    trim: true,
    unique: false,
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 6,
    maxLength: 100,
    uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
  },

  categoryHistory: {
    type: Number,
    enum: CategoryHistoryEnum.Category_History,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },

  payeeId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },

  pointDirection: {
    default: false,
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

**this res**

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "Your request is successfully executed",
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "userId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "date": "2022-11-18 11:1 pm",
                "point": 50,
                "description": "test",
                "categoryHistory": 3,
                "payeeId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "pointDirection": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "id": "6377e495541a7889acf1cfc6"
            },
            {
                "userId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "date": "2022-11-18 11:2 pm",
                "point": 50,
                "description": "test",
                "categoryHistory": 3,
                "payeeId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "pointDirection": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "id": "6377e4c4541a7889acf1cfdb"
            },
            {
                "userId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a7741",
                "date": "2022-11-19 12:27 am",
                "point": 5,
                "description": "test",
                "categoryHistory": 2,
                "payeeId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "pointDirection": false,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "id": "6377f8bbe8ca063c5a5deef4"
            }
        ],
        "paginator": {
            "itemCount": 3,
            "offset": 0,
            "perPage": 10,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "currentPage": 1,
            "slNo": 1,
            "hasPrevPage": false,
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "prev": null,
            "next": null
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to make the result as follows

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "Your request is successfully executed",
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "userId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "date": "2022-11-18 11:1 pm",
                "point": 50,
                "description": "test",
                "categoryHistory": 3,
                "payeeId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "pointDirection": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "id": "6377e495541a7889acf1cfc6"
            },
            {
                "userId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "date": "2022-11-18 11:2 pm",
                "point": 50,
                "description": "test",
                "categoryHistory": 3,
                "payeeId": "6372886e89d36d38b75a774b",
                "pointDirection": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "id": "6377e4c4541a7889acf1cfdb"
            },      

        ],
 

        "total point": 100,              // Add This to res //



        "paginator": {
            "itemCount": 3,
            "offset": 0,
            "perPage": 10,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "currentPage": 1,
            "slNo": 1,
            "hasPrevPage": false,
            "hasNextPage": false,
            "prev": null,
            "next": null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I've understood correctly but in your aggregation pipeline you can add a new step to create the field `total` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/okZ_K-aSmR3)

Comment: @J.F.thank you for replying Can you explain to me where to add the attached code in the example that you sent me? I tried this on my application and the result was that it did not recognize the db.  ("message": "db is not defined",)